How to use isolated CSS in a MAUI Hybrid app
I have a Component.razor file.
When I include inline css, it is correctly applied. However, when I include it in Component.razor.css file, it is not applied anymore. Is there anything else to do in a Maui Hybrid app to be able to use isolated css ? What is missing here ?
